# No internet connection on trying to record traffic from a android app with JMeter

Tags: android, jmeter, recording

Trying to record traffic from mobile via jmeter, but once all setup is done internet is not working.

Steps followed:

1. jmeter template with thread group, recording controller, view results tree and https test script recorder (port no: 8091). Then started recording, collected certificate from bin folder (stopped recording at this time) and installed certificate in mobile device.
2. In mobile wifi connection added proxy to manual with local ip address of computer and port mentioned in jmeter recorder (port no: 8091).

Then again started the recording from jmeter by pressing start, but this makes mobile internet connection completely off, can't access internet in browser or app or anything until the mobile wifi proxy setting changed to none from manual.

Please do suggest what needs to be done? Thank you in advance.

referred blogs and solutons:

1.https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/how-to-record-android-application-using-https-traffic-jmeter/

2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57144306/7193173
3. https://flood.io/blog/ask-a-flooder-06-how-to-record-traffic-from-a-mobile-app-with-jmeter-video

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say what's going on without seeing [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) and output of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

I can think of the following possible reasons:

1. Your operating system [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) is blocking incoming connections to port 8091
2. The machine where you're running JMeter and the android device aren't in the same [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) therefore Android device cannot reach JMeter hence you cannot use it as the proxy
3. JMeter must have internet access as well so if you're [being the corporate proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) - you need to make JMeter aware of this upstream proxy
4. Starting from [Android 7.0](https://www.android.com/versions/nougat-7-0/) you need to take [some extra steps](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices-Recording-Using-Android-Devices) in order to be able to intercept applications traffic

Comment: I checked 1. netstat -a -n to confirm 8091 port is listening, 2. jmeter and android device are in same subnet checked using ipconfig in windows and under wifi settings connection under mobile, 3. connected mobile and laptop to home hotspot, 4. has taken care this settngs with help of developer and have taken new debug apk from new build. Can we please connect over @Dmitri , it would be helpful?